# Como desabilitar a converçao ";)" para emoji no WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Inseri um conteúdo em uma página WordPress eu coloquei um `;)` e ele transformou em emoji.

Como posso arrumar isso no WordPress?

Answer (score 3):

Pode adicionar o plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/emoji-settings/

e então nas configurações remova o opção *Enable emoji support*:

[image: emoji settings]

E clique em <kbd>Save Changes</kbd>

> **Nota:** Se estiver usando RocketCache ou SuperCache, que são plugins de otimização e cache back-end para Wordpress, talvez tenha que limpar eles para que atualize, ou então aguardar.